# Function takes 1 argument but 2 were given, but I don't see where I did that

Tags: python

I'm working on a game where I can create a character with the char function. `tSt ()` is supposed to represent the character's stats at any given level. This is the entire script so far.

Unfortunately it causes:

```
TypeError : st () takes 1 argument but 2 were given.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
g=1.08
h=1.1
j=1.12

mage = [g,g,g,j,h,h] # these are essentially classes of characters, affecting stat growth.
warrior = [h,j,h,g,g,h]
ranger = [h,g,g,g,h,j]
paladin = [j,h,g,h,g,h]


class char :
    def __init__ (x,name,l,spec,stats):
        x.name = name
        x.spec = spec # class, as mentioned above by mage.
        x.stats = stats # base stats.
        x.l = l # level of character.

    def n (x):
        return (x.name)

    def sp (x):
        return x.spec

    def lv (x):
        return x.l

    def st (x):
        return x.stats


def tSt (x):
    a=[]
    for i in x.st():
        a[i]=x.st([i])*x.sp([i])*(x.lv()-1)
    return a # this is meant to change the stats to the appropriate value based on the level. It's meant to be equal to level*stat*modifier.


c1 = char ('andrè the giant mage',1,mage,[500,100,])

a = tSt (c1)
```

Comment: functions inside classes all have to have "self" as the first argument.

Comment: def st(self,x):

Comment: Also, do yourself a favour and give functions proper names

Comment: None of the functions you've shown here are actually needed anyway, so yes, you should make them instance methods but you'd be better off just using the fields

Comment: The problem is here: a[i]=x.st([i]) You pass [i] as a parameter but the method expects only one parameter 'x' (should be self) and self is always passed to the method. So now it gets 2 parameters: self and [i]

Comment: You do not need to include self. You've already included it but just named it `x` instead. Against convention but it works. The problem is when you call `x.st([i])`. You're calling it with an argument it can't take

Answer (score 0):

Please add `"self"` as 1st parameter of your class methods, example:

```
def my_function(self, my_parameter)
```

This will allow you to reach methods and member variables from the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` as the first parameter. It should be the first parameter in a normal function of a class.

```
def st (self, x):
        return x.stats
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at member functions which should have the signature like `st(self, x)`.

Maybe it helps if you bend your mind and think that given a class `Foo`:

```py
class Foo:
    def a_method(self, x):
        print(x)
```

if you create an instance `foo` of it:

```py
foo = Foo()
```

then calling

```py
foo.a_method("hello")
```

is basically a syntactic sugar of

```py
Foo.a_method(foo, "hello")
```

where it's obvious that you have two parameters to pass.